# Converting string to float or decimal sometimes results in long precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string which I want to convert to a decimal.
eg.

```
tax_rate = "0.07"
tax_rate.to_d
```

In most cases it converts to `0.07` but sometimes it converts it to `0.07000000000000001`. Why?

If it helps, when I look at the log of when I insert this value into the DB, this is the relevant part:

```
["tax_rate", #<BigDecimal:7f9b6221d7c0,'0.7000000000 000001E-1',18(45)>]
```

Hopefully that makes sense to someone.

**Disclaimer:**
I have a feeling someone is going to ask *why* I'm doing this.
I've created a simple settings model, where a user can update some global settings.
The `Setting` model has `name`, `value` and `var_type` columns.
The `value` column is a string. I use a helper method to retrieve the value in the appropriate format depending on the value of the `var_type` column.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain *why* but there is a chance I can tell you how to avoid having this kind of trouble when dealing with numbers: use rationals.

Here is the documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Rational.html

As stated, a rational will always give you the exact number you want and thus will avoid rounding errors.

From the doc:

```
10.times.inject(0){|t,| t + 0.1}              #=> 0.9999999999999999
10.times.inject(0){|t,| t + Rational('0.1')}  #=> (1/1)
```

Let me know if this solves your problem. : )